# Not getting the URL of Update api in DJANGO

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

Creating an api for create schedule for doctor,through which doctor will feed his whole week timings.That will work on update.
I am trying to create update api ,using primary key,but i am not getting the url of update api in postman.If i changes to create then i am getting the url.
Some one do guide me.
models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patient_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient_name)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    doctor_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.doctor_name)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    doctor=models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DAYS=(('Mon','Monday'),
    ('Tue','Tuesday'),
    ('Wed','Wednesday'),
    ('Thu','Thursday'),
    ('Fri','Friday'),
    ('Sat','Saturday'),
    ('Sun','Sunday'),
    )
    days=models.CharField(choices=DAYS,max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    start_time=models.TimeField()
    end_time=models.TimeField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.doctor)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor=models.ForeignKey(Doctor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date=models.DateField()
    time_slot=models.TimeField()

views.py

class PatViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self,request):
        # permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope]
        try:
            data=request.data

            patient_name=data.get('patient_name')
            if not patient_name:
                raise Exception("Enter the patient_name")
            
            patient_obj=Patient()
            patient_obj.patient_name=patient_name
            patient_obj.save()
            return Response({"success": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        except Exception as error:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class DocViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self,request):
        # permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope]
        try:
            data=request.data

            doctor_name=data.get('doctor_name')
            if not doctor_name:
                raise Exception("Enter the doctor_name")
            
            docotr_obj=Doctor()
            docotr_obj.doctor_name=doctor_name
            docotr_obj.save()
            return Response({"success": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        except Exception as error:
            #traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class TotalViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def update(self,request,pk):
        try:
            data=request.data
            doctor=Doctor.objects.get(pk=pk)
            print(doctor)
            timings=data.get('schedule')
            DAYS=Schedule.DAYS
            for day in DAYS:
                sch=Schedule()
                sch.doctor=doctor
                sch.days=day[0]
                sch.start_time=timings[day[1]]['start_time']
                sch.end_time=timings[day[1]]['end_time']
                sch.save()
            return Response({"success": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        except Exception as error:
            #traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

urls.py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from doctor import views
from .views import*
router=DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Patient', views.PatViewSet, basename='PatViewSet')
router.register(r'Sch', views.TotalViewSet, basename='TotalViewSet')
router.register(r'Doctor', views.DocViewSet, basename='DocViewSet')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [UpdateView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview) in your case which is quite straightforward.

it will make your work easy and clean.

Comment: do i need to use serializers for that?

Comment: For better design pattern and to keep database schema and business logic separate I would suggest yes. You should use serializers if not using now.